# Post video to wall from IOS, through server

Tags: facebook, video, post

I've done a fair bit of searching for this, but can't seem to find an answer for this specific problem. I'm fairly new to web development as well, so forgive me if the answer is right in front of my eyes.

I have an IOS app which needs to allow a user to post a video to his FB wall, which is created from content the user creates from within the app.

However, the rendering of the video is too processor-instensive for the device itself, so I'm hoping to do something like the following:

1. Allow the user to authenticate the post, using the IOS login.
2. When this happens, ipload an xml file to a remote server which has all the data needed to render the video.
3. This server is running a custom app which will render the video and then complete the post operation, uploading the video with the user's credentials and posting it to their wall.

Is this possible? If not, can anyone suggest alternatives? Maybe I could host the file somewhere else and then simply post a link to it on the wall directly from the app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this tutorial is what you want:
[How-To: Use the Graph API to Upload a Video (iOS)](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/532)

You'll obviously have to tweak it since you're doing the upload server side, but should be able to figure that out.  The basics you'll needto do:

- have the iOS app log the user in and grant the correct permissions
- after login, keep track of the user's facebook access token
- When submitting the video-generation request to your server, include the user's access token
- When the server is ready to post, it uses that access token to post on the user's behalf.